# How to simplify $\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}{1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}{1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}$$

I have been staring at it for ages and know that it simplifies to $x$, but have been unable to make any significant progress.

I have tried doing $(\frac{1-x}{1-2x})(\frac{1+2x}{1+2x})$ but that doesn't help as it leaves $\frac{1+x-2x^2}{1-4x^2}$ any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing to solve here. Perhaps you want to *simplify* the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}{1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}$$
(take L.C.M. in numerator and denominator)
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{{(1-2x)}-{(1-x)}}{1-2x}}{\dfrac{(1-2x)-2{(1-x)}}{1-2x}}$$
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{1-2x-1+x}{1-2x}}{\dfrac{1-2x-2+2x}{1-2x}}$$
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{-x}{1-2x}}{\dfrac{-1}{1-2x}}$$
since $$\dfrac{\dfrac ab}{\dfrac cd}=\dfrac ab\times\dfrac {d}{c}$$
so

$${\dfrac{-x}{1-2x}}\times{\dfrac{1-2x}{-1}}$$
$$x$$

Comment: Dear downvoter can you leave a comment that points to my mistake thanks

Answer (score 8):

Hint:$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ where $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1-2x}$,$(x\ne 1/2)$

Solution:Here $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1-x}{1-2x}$.We know that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and as  $\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}{1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}=f^{-1}(f(x))$ so it follows that $\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}{1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ So we dont need to simplify.

(Here $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}>0$ so $f^{-1} $ exists.)

Comment: So multiply everything by the inverse?!

Comment: This solution is so elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}{1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}} = \frac{\frac{-x}{1-2x}}{\frac{-1}{1-2x}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

When four storey fractions are involved, it's better to do computations separately. Write
$$
N=1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x},\qquad
D=1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}
$$
and work on $N$ and $D$:
\begin{align}
N&=1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}\\
&=\frac{(1-2x)-(1-x)}{1-2x}\\
&=\frac{1-2x-1+x}{1-2x}\\
&=\frac{-x}{1-2x}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
D&=1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}\\
&=\frac{(1-2x)-2(1-x)}{1-2x}\\
&=\frac{1-2x-2+2x}{1-2x}\\
&=\frac{-1}{1-2x}
\end{align}
Now you know that your fraction is
$$
\frac{N}{D}=N\cdot\frac{1}{D}=\frac{-x}{1-2x}\cdot\frac{1-2x}{-1}
=\frac{-x}{-1}=x
$$

Answer (score 2):

> $$\frac{1 - \frac{1-x}{1 - 2x}}{1 - 2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}$$

Multiplying through by $1-2x$ gives

$$\frac{1 - 2x - (1 - x)}{1 - 2x - 2(1 - x)}.$$

Expanding the brackets and then simplifying gives

$$\frac{1 - 2x - 1 + x}{1 - 2x - 2 + 2x}$$
$$= \frac{-x}{-1} = x.$$

**NOTE:** This method works well because you have the same "denominator" of $1 - 2x$ every where. If you had different ones, I  would recommend the finding the lowest common denominator method that is your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1-2x}}{1-2\frac{1-x}{1-2x}} = \frac{\frac{-x}{1-2x}}{\frac{-1}{1-2x}} = \frac{-x}{1-2x} \frac{1-2x}{-1} = \frac{-x(1-2x)}{-1(1-2x)} = \frac{-x}{-1} = x.$$